# Несколько слайдеров аккордеон на странице

Tags: jquery, html

Всем доброго времени суток. Возник такой вопрос. Есть [слайдер](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/). Вроде бы с ним разобрался. Но появился такая задача: нужно сделать несколько разных слайдеров на одной странице. Ответ типа сделать им разные классы и несколько раз инициализировать слайдер не годится. Контент на странице будет создаваться автоматический из базы. Ну или если есть другие варианты подобных слайдеров - готов посмотреть в их сторону.

Comment: @alexfedosienko, После того, как другие участники форума ответили на ваш вопрос, нужно просмотреть ответы и 1) проголосовать за полезные с вашей точки зрения, 2) принять лучший, тот, который вам действительно помог. Очень важно голосовать за ответы и принимать их, не забывайте об этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ответ типа сделать им разные классы и несколько раз инициализировать слайдер не годится.

Почему? Ведь можно так сделать:

```
<div class="slider">
    <ol>
        ...
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="slider">
    <ol>
        ...
    </ol>
</div>

// и так далее
```

А потом для каждого инициализировать свой слайдер:

```
$(".slider").each(function(){
    $(this).liteAccordion();
});
```

[И всё работает](http://jsfiddle.net/NgE5b/embedded/result/)

Comment: Спасибо, видать где то с настройками нумудрил.